# Understanding PromiseValue returned from "then" using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

These 2 code blocks function exactly the same in a snippet from an Angular 2 service. If there is only one statement in the function body of the "then", is it safe to say that a "return" statement is unnecessary and that these blocks of code are identical in operation?

```
getTodos(): Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.todosUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as Todo[])
```

This code block has a "return" statement in the "then"

```
getTodos(): Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.todosUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => { return response.json() as Todo[]})
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: See also [Syntax of arrow functions, to use or not to use {} around the body](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40636513/1048572)

Comment: I see this...
"(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression"
is equivalent to: 
"(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }"
from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions